# Masters Degree vs Masters Certificate / Diploma in Canada

Tags: masters, canada

I've seen prominent Canadian Universities (York and University of Toronto, for example) offer a Masters Certificate and Masters Diploma respectively in the subject of financial engineering. How do these differ from a masters degree (in the scope of Canada)?

Comment: Does nobody know?

Comment: I hope this is helpful this late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master's Certificates and Diplomas are typically offered from programs that aren't accredited yet. This does not mean that the institution isnt accredited, just not that particular degree. They also typically take less time than a Master's Degree.

Comment: So the word masters doesn't really mean much in the context?

Comment: No, Masters just simply suggests it is work done at a graduate level, but not an actual degree.